# Computing a square root in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pdftex, luatex, number

We can simply compute approximations of the square roots of numbers, using these (mainly pure TeX) macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\liczba
\newcount\kwadrat
\def\sqroot#1{\liczba=0\kwadrat=0
\loop
\ifnum\kwadrat<#1 \advance\liczba by1 \kwadrat\liczba \multiply \kwadrat by \liczba 
\repeat$\sqrt{#1}\approx\the\liczba$}


\sqroot{121}

\sqroot{300}

\sqroot{626}

\end{document}
```

Are there better methods? In particular, if we want to use these values in TikZ.

Comment: Just curious: isn't that task easier using Lua(TeX) `math.sqrt`? If you want arbitrary precision and portability is your concern, there are some pure Lua libraries wandering there.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Hence I am adding also `luatex` tag. However standard TeX solutions are preferred.

Comment: If you want to use the results in TikZ, why not use the calc library? It has a `sqrt` function.

Comment: Look at `pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex`. It has a TeX definition in, also for other functions.

Comment: The `xfp` package has `\fpeval{sqrt(<expression>)}` which works on any engine with e-TeX

Comment: @JairoA.delRio - please see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577309/5001) I just posted. :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\newcount\liczba
\newcount\kwadrat
\def\sqroot#1{\liczba=0\kwadrat=0
\loop
\ifnum\kwadrat<#1 \advance\liczba by1 \kwadrat\liczba \multiply \kwadrat by \liczba
\repeat$\sqrt{#1}\approx\the\liczba$}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bettersquareroot}{O{16}m}{%
  \fpeval{round(sqrt(#2),#1)}%
}


\sqroot{121} and \bettersquareroot{121}

\sqroot{300} and \bettersquareroot[5]{300}

\sqroot{626} and \bettersquareroot{626}

\end{document}
```

Much better, isn't it?

[image]

If you want integer approximation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\newcount\liczba
\newcount\kwadrat
\def\sqroot#1{\liczba=0\kwadrat=0
\loop
\ifnum\kwadrat<#1 \advance\liczba by1 \kwadrat\liczba \multiply \kwadrat by \liczba 
\repeat$\sqrt{#1}\approx\the\liczba$}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bettersquareroot}{m}{%
  \fpeval{round(sqrt(#1),0)}%
}


\sqroot{121} and \bettersquareroot{121}

\sqroot{300} and \bettersquareroot{300}

\sqroot{626} and \bettersquareroot{626}

\sqroot{652} and \bettersquareroot{652}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can also use the previous, more general, code with

```
\bettersquareroot[0]{652}
```

Note that this is fully expandable, so you can use in any context you need an integer.

Comment: I have removed comments here concerning the accuracy of the output; one may compare the stated values to for example Wolfram Alpha to see how accurate they are, e.g. [sqrt(626.2)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28626.2%29)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Much better, indeed.

Answer (score 13):

If you are already using TikZ, you could as well use `\pgfmathparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcount\liczba
\newcount\kwadrat
\def\sqroot#1{\liczba=0\kwadrat=0
\loop
\ifnum\kwadrat<#1 \advance\liczba by1 \kwadrat\liczba \multiply \kwadrat by \liczba 
\repeat$\sqrt{#1}\approx\the\liczba$}

\newcommand\pgfsqrt[1]{\pgfmathparse{int((sqrt(#1)))}\pgfmathresult}

\sqroot{121} and \pgfsqrt{121}

\sqroot{300} and \pgfsqrt{300}

\sqroot{626} and \pgfsqrt{626}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It employs the Lua library functions `math.sqrt` and `math.ceil`. (The latter function returns the smallest integer that's no smaller than its argument; thus `\math.ceil(11.0)` returns `11`, whereas `math.ceil(11.01)` returns `12`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\sqroot[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(math.sqrt(#1))}}
\newcommand\approxsqroot[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(math.ceil(math.sqrt(#1)))}}
   
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
$\sqrt{121}=\sqroot{121}=\approxsqroot{121}$
$\sqrt{300}\approx\sqroot{300}\le\approxsqroot{300}$
$\sqrt{626}\approx\sqroot{626}\le\approxsqroot{626}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

It is incomprehensible to me to decipher your code (I'm sorry). I would simply suggest to you to use `calculator` package, using `\TRUNCATE[0]`, to have integer number. The image is taken from the manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{calculator}
  

\begin{document}
\SQUAREROOT{121}{\sola}
$\sqrt{121}=\sola$
$\approx$ \TRUNCATE[0]{\sola}{\solA}
\solA


\SQUAREROOT{300}{\solb}
$\sqrt{300}=\solb$
$\approx$
\TRUNCATE[0]{\solb}{\solB}
\solB

\SQUAREROOT{626}{\solc}
$\sqrt{626}=\solc$
$\approx$
\TRUNCATE[0]{\solc}{\solC}
\solC
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: I need integer approximation, but I understand that it is also possible.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Ah, now I have understood. Excuse me.

Comment: Your answer is OK. I have just upvoted it. I am simply looking for a number of approaches.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke See with truncate if it is better instead of before. I don't understand all these complicated codes :-(

Comment: The code is simple: I am computing the squares of consecutive naturals until they are larger than our number. To my surprise, it is pretty quick.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke You always do a step too many if the number is not a perfect square.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I understand very little about it, sorry. But your question has been voted :-)

Comment: @egreg Certainly, but it is an easy step.